# What are good reasons to use explicit interface implementation for the sole purpose of hiding members?

Tags: c#, design, interfaces

During one of my studies into the intricacies of C#, I came across an interesting passage concerning explicit interface implementation.

`While this syntax is quite helpful when you need to resolve name clashes,
    you can use explicit interface implementation simply to hide more "advanced"
    members from the object level.`

The difference between allowing the use of `object.method()` or requiring the casting of `((Interface)object).method()` seems like mean-spirited obfuscation to my inexperienced eyes. The text noted that this will hide the method from Intellisense at the object level, but why would you *want* to do that if it was not necessary to avoid name conflicts?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/392516/Why-I-use-explicit-interface-implementation-as-a-d

Answer (score 12):

Imagine a situation where an interface forces a class to implement methods which do not actually make sense as part of the class.  This can often happen when interfaces are particularly large and violate the Interface Segregation Principle.

This class needs to implement the interface, but instead of polluting its highly visible public interface with methods that do not make sense, you can explicitly implement those methods which you do not want to be obviously available.  The highly visible public interface of the class is how you want the class to be used, and the explicit implementation is there when the class is accessed through the interface.

Comment: Is it just me, or does this sound like a terrible idea?

Comment: @Kevin, how so?  Sometimes the interface is out of your control, and you have to use it.  Mitigating the damage of an overbearing interface seems reasonable.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that many times the real world gets in the way of the right way of doing things.  @Kevin yes it's a terrible idea but sometimes you don't have a choice and have to work with the slop - better to hide it away and make a facade of doing things properly when you can't **really** do it properly.

Comment: @Wayne, I understand your reasoning for wanting/using such a system. Hell, I'd probably use it to in exactly the case you state. I guess my short comment was really just pointing out that this is improper, so why allow it in the language.

Comment: @Kevin Here is an example from memory.  You are implementing "ConcurrentDictionary".  Your class has to support being read like an IDictionary, so it can be used in classes that know how to read from IDictionary.  So, you add these new functions that allow you to write safely like AddOrUpdate.  To discourage the use of the non-threadsafe writing members you explicitly implement them.

Comment: Arguably, this could have been solved if the original language creators had made a IReadOnlyDictionary, but they didn't, so you're stuck with what you have if you want to keep using existing older functions.  You're also free to choose of those explicit implementations should throw a NotImplementedException, depending on if you want more compatibility or safety.

Comment: Excessive interface separation can be a major obstacle to composition and aggregation.  Consider, for example, that one wishes to have an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` which behaves as the concatenation of two others.  If `IEnumerable<T>` included a property to say whether its count was known, potentially infinite, or neither, along with a method to ask what its count was, a class which aggregates multiple `IEnumerable<T>` and behaves as a concatenation could efficiently report its count in the case that some of the encapsulated collections knew their counts.

Comment: As it is, the only way for an aggregating class to offer such a feature in the case where all constituents happen to support it would be for a factory method to check all constituents for all features of interest before the aggregating instance is constructed.  Not nearly as clean as having the aggregate implement methods of a broader interface, and respond to queries about its abilities by querying its constituents, if and when such abilities are of interest to clients.

Answer (score 4):

The most useful application I found is with implementing factories. In many cases, it is useful to create classes that are mutable inside the factory but immutable to external classes. This can be easily implemented in Java using inner classes, by making the fields and their setters private and only exposing the getters as public members. However in C#, I had to use explicit interfaces to achieve the same thing. I'll explain further:

In Java, the inner class AND the outer class can access private members of each other, which makes total sense as the classes are very closely related. They are in the same code file and are probably developed by the same developer. This means that private fields and methods in the inner class can still be accessed by the factory to modify their values. But external classes will not be able to access these fields except through their public getters.

However, in C#, outer classes cannot access private members of inner classes so that concept is not directly applicable. I used an explicit interface as a workaround by defining a private interface in the outer class and explicitly implementing it in the inner class. This way, only the outer class can access the methods in this interface the same way it is done in Java (but they have to be methods, not fields).

**Example:**

```cs
public class Factory
{
    // factory method to create a hard-coded Mazda Tribute car.
    public static Car CreateCar()
    {
        Car car = new Car();

        // the Factory class can modify the model because it has access to
        // the private ICarSetters interface
        ((ICarSetters)car).model = "Mazda Tribute";

        return car;
    }

    // define a private interface containing the setters.
    private interface ICarSetters
    {
        // define the setter in the private interface
        string model { set; }
    }

    // This is the inner class. It has a member "model" that should not be modified
    // but clients, but should be modified by the factory.
    public class Car: ICarSetters
    {
        // explicitly implement the setter
        string ICarSetters.model { set; }

        // create a public getter
        public string model { get; }
    }
}

class Client
{
    public Client()
    {
        Factory.Car car = Factory.CreateCar();

        // can only read model because only the getter is public
        // and ICarSetters is private to Factory
        string model = car.model;
    }
}
```

That is what I would use explicit interfaces for.

Answer (score 4):

If a class implements two interfaces that contain a member with the same signature, then implementing that member on the class will cause both interfaces to use that member as their implementation. In the following example, all the calls to `Paint` invoke the same method.
C#

```
class Test 
{
    static void Main()

    {
        SampleClass sc = new SampleClass();
        IControl ctrl = (IControl)sc;
        ISurface srfc = (ISurface)sc;

        // The following lines all call the same method.
        sc.Paint();
        ctrl.Paint();
        srfc.Paint();
    }
}


interface IControl
{
    void Paint();
}
interface ISurface
{
    void Paint();
}
class SampleClass : IControl, ISurface
{
    // Both ISurface.Paint and IControl.Paint call this method. 
    public void Paint()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Paint method in SampleClass");
    }
}
```

In contrast, explicit implementation of one (or both) of them allows you to specify different behavior for each.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit interfaces are handy when either an object has two or more very distinct forms of communication.

For example, an object that maintains a collection of child objects that need to communicate with parent.

There are some actions we only want accessible to external callers and some actions we only want accessible to the child objects.

Explicit interfaces help ensure this divide.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parent = new Parent();
        parent.DoExternalStuff();
    }

    interface IExternal {
        void DoExternalStuff();
    }

    interface IInternal {
        void DoInternalStuff();
    }

    class Parent : IExternal, IInternal
    {
        public Parent()
        {
            var child = new Child(this);
        }

        public void DoExternalStuff()
        {
           // do something exciting here for external callers
        }

        void IInternal.DoInternalStuff()
        {
            // do something exciting here for internal callers
        }
    }

    class Child
    {
        public Child(IInternal parent)
        {
            parent.DoInternalStuff();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you had functionality that was useful to the users, but only if you really know what you're doing (enough to have read the documentation to learn about the function) but that is likely to break things if you don't.

Why you'd do that rather than providing, say a second "advanced features interface" I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Code is generally read more than it is written and I only use Intellisense to write code quickly.  I wouldn't write code a particular way just to make Intellisense nicer.

I don't particularly see how

((Interface)object).method() is any more readable than object.method().

If I had a lot of methods on a particular object, I might question whether or not its a god object and should actually be broken into multiple simpler objects.